# What Is The Title of This Type of Program

Tags: raspberry-pi

In the same vein that; a graphical program someone uses is called a GUI (Graphical User Interface), a program that talks with machinery and displays statuses to an operator are called an HMI (Human Machine Interface), a program that uses a console is called a console application, what would the appropriate title for a program that runs on computer and boots at startup and only allows users to interact with the program and not whats underneath? Similar to banking software or the checkout software at grocery stores.

It will be on a Raspberry PI with a touchscreen and as soon as the PI powers on, it will load this program that covers the whole screen and doesn't allow the user to interact with the PI through desktop or console.

*EDIT*

I am wanting to study up on best practices for this type of program, I just don't know WHAT to search for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that is typically referred to as a "[Kiosk program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiosk_software)".

Comment: from what i read, that is exactly what i am looking for. Thanks @kmote

Answer (score 0):

For a very general description: What you are looking for is an Input/Output System (IOS) it manages what the computer sees from the users input. All programs are Input/Output Systems, what you are describing is closer to a High Level "Basic Input Output System"(BIOS) that all computers use to start a computer, it starts at launch in all computers before the operating system is run, your program starts after the operating system starts. A fitting definition would be an Advanced Input/Output System or (AIOS)

Side Note: A Graphical User Interface or (GUI) describes the visual portion of software on a given system. It is a device or program enabling a user to communicate with a computer. All software needs to have a GUI, including you Advanced Input/Output System (AIOS)